# Visual Studio can not resolve tns

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2012, tnsnames, tnsping

i have a problem for a while but suddenly it became a terminal error since i got to do this task 'today'. i already tried everything suggested.

caused by a problem at installing oracle i found a workaround and i connect to database with connectionstring below, which works:

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.1)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MYDATABASE)));User ID=myusername;Password=mypassword;
```

and in that database i have a connections table which my datalayer uses to connect to other databases.
so here begins the problem. when i try to connect to other databases i get the error: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified.

long story short: i can not touch that table. tnsping does work, so does toad. but plsql developer and visual studio can not. i mean there should be a problem with listener, sqlora, tnsnames or such specific oracle file and i cant find what.

Comment: "when i try to connect to other databases i get the error" - so can you connect to `MYDATABASE` on 192.168.1.1 and get data from your table, and it's only when you make another connection based on that data that you see the error? If so we'd need to see what data you're using and how you're connecting with it.

Comment: yes. lets make it more clear. like i said toad, tnsping and torasql can connect. but vs or plsql can not. vs cant connect when i use a proper connection string. normally vs will connect to it through tns. in my situation, i write full tns to connectionstring. so vs can connect. but with a normal conn string it can not.

Answer (score 0):

for VS i'd try putting the tnsnames.ora in the bin folder of the app. For sqlplus i'd check that it is in C:\Orant\